# magento1.9.1.0 multi shipping not redirecting to payment gateway page after clicking on place order button

Tags: magento

I am using magento community 1.9.1.0.

When trying to checkout using multi shipping method then everything works fine but after placing order it directly takes me to order success page saying 'Thank you for your purchase'.

User/customer is not getting redirected to payment gateway page for filling the details of credit/debit card. How can an order be successful?

I am also new to magento so, please help me to proceed in the right direction.

Also, from the two payment method i am using it is only showing me one in multi shipping method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: It's about magento an ecommerce content management system question.

Comment: If you know anything about magento 1.9.1.0 then please answer the question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site. If this isn't about programming you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity !

Comment: See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16628/multiple-checkout-payment-gateway-redirection-issue/16644

Comment: did you found any solution for this question?